# wget --include-directories

Tags: wildcards, wget

I am trying to download all subfolders and files from web page by using wget

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 --include-directories="entry_*" http://test.test/root/
```

I need only directories that starts with "entry_"
So by executing command I've provided above I am able to get only index.html file.
Is something wrong with my command?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so I found a problem. I did not include full path for include-directories flag. 
So command should look like

```
wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 --include-directories="root/entry_*" http://test.test/root/
```